# Why is it better for the scope of a variable declaration to be limited to the minimum required?

Tags: variables, scope, limit

As in, I have been told that it's better to keep a certain variable within a method rather than using it class-wide. But why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is :

1 variable for 1 usage. Don't do

```
int i=0;
//some code using i

//some other code not using i

//a new code using i because you just need an int and i is already there
```

you can or declare a new variable, or even declare 2 nested scopes. **why ?** because if you forget to reinitialized the variable for the second usage, then you have something wrong.

Also having 1 variable per usage is a often better to give good names to variable and not names like : i, counter, value, tmp. Prefer specific names that would make your code more readable.

Also if you use variable only in one small scope it will just take a bit of memory dynamically on the stack for the time you use it. If you put it in a very huge scope with a lot a variable, you will have more local variables in the debugger (harder to debug) and you will use the memory for longer lifetime than what you really need( this is not so bad for small variables but can be bad for big ones, like STL containers and stuff. And in general being used to apply this coding style to any kind of variable even small will help you to do it for big variables too)

And in you message you talk about having a variable as object member instead of just local variable in the function. Again that makes your object bigger, There might be some part of the code where this variable is not used, or not initialised.

All this is style but helps you to do less mistakes. You should only have 1 variable per usage, only the time you use it and initialized it as soon as you create the variable.

[google cpp guidelines about scoping of local variables](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Local_Variables)

Comment: Thanks, this was very explanatory.

Comment: your welcome, but you can find good information in a lot of place about this. You can take a look at the c++ guidelines of google also see edit